# How to eliminate Vowels from a string in java?

Tags: java, string

I want to eliminate vowels from a String, I can eliminate them, but I fail to return them to `main()`. I got the exact output by using the following code.

```
String string = "ajeIokluj";    
String s = string.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]","");   
return s;
```

It will be great if the required output came by using for loop.

Comment: Why you want a for loop instead of a single replaceAll function?

Comment: you have already used a better technique, why use a for-loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "but I failed to return them to main()"? What result did you get and what did you expect?

Comment: and how did this not return correct output to main? everything seems correct

Comment: Actually I tried with switch case included in a for loop in that case I tried to return the output to main(), but resulting o/p on console is a single letter. @Pshemo

Comment: can you share your code how you are using for loop and return output to main()? Probably that would help becuase as @Vihar said everything seems correct and you have used the best possible technique to removed vowels no need to use for loop for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you have written the code similar to below considering your `fail to return` statement .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "ajeIokluj";    
        String s = eliminateVowels(string);   
        System.out.println(s); 
    }

    private static String eliminateVowels(String string) {
        String s = string.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]","");
        return s;
    }
```

If you did it works perfectly fine and if not use above as reference ;)

Based on your comments since you looking for specifically using `for` loop (Which is not recommended) please find code below.

```
public static String removeVowels(final String string){
        final String vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(final char c : string.toCharArray())
            if(vowels.indexOf(c) < 0)
                builder.append(c);
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: I coded the same as you and I got the output too. What I need is same the output by using for loop.

Comment: i have updated my answer. Though its not recommended way. Out of my curiosity can you help me understand why you want to use for loop in this scenario ?

Comment: I want use for loop to improve my coding skills.

Comment: fare enough... hope my answer helps. In case you need more help. do leave a comment. ;) Happy learning

Answer (score 0):

```
public class main {
    public static String removeVowels(String word) {
        String ret = "";
        String realRet = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if ("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(word.charAt(i)) == -1) {
                ret += word.charAt(i);
            }
        }
         realRet = realRet + ret.charAt(0) + ret.charAt(1);
        return realRet.toLowerCase() ;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String pass = removeVowels("Your String");
        for(int i=0 ; i < 3; i++) {
            pass =  pass + (int) (Math.random() * 100) ;
        }

        System.out.println(pass);
    }
}
```

Try this it may work you!!